# Comparing columns in Google sheets to find count of values not common with rest

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an example google sheet (actual data I'm processing is sensitive).

I only want the number of people. (eg. X number of people have Red (but not Orange, Green, Blue).

Link to Google sheet so it's easier to understand and try formulas:

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-lmlpOaWSLjEe8zMOu5krma5dpZXHITqXEmPsnppD8o/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: Added the below formulas to the [Horanimal_copy_Sheet4](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-lmlpOaWSLjEe8zMOu5krma5dpZXHITqXEmPsnppD8o/edit#gid=1067760214&range=D5) tab for easier viewing.*

**Step-by Step Instructions:**

1. Grab a list of unique names by entering `=UNIQUE($A$2:$A)` in cell `D5`.
2. Count how many times each name has an entry by entering `=BYROW(D5:D,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",COUNTIF($A$2:$A,r))))` in cell `E5`.
3. To show any person with only one entry (*“eg. Person X has value Red but no other colors.”*) enter `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E5:E=1,XLOOKUP(D5:D,$A$2:$A,$B$2:$B,"",0,1),""))` in cell `F5`.
   This will return the only color associated with that person and nothing for the people with multiple colors.
4. Create a column for every possible color in a cell of your choosing (like `E2`) with `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE($B$2:$B))`
5. Finally, for each possible color, count the number of times it is the only color associated with a person. In `E3` enter `=BYCOL(E2:2,LAMBDA(c,IF(c="","",COUNTIF($F$5:$F,c))))`

*This setup will work regardless of how many people you have or how many colors you have and will expand to accommodate any additions or contract for any removals automatically.*

*To recap...*
**We go from raw list** (which can continue to grow vertically):
[image]

**To a list of all individuals, how many colors they're associated with, and if only associated with 1, which color that is** (which can also continue to grow vertically and be any length):
[image]

**To finally arrive at a count of how many times a color appears as the only color associated with a person:** (which can expand horizontally as colors are added)
[image]

***Expansion example:**
When I add an entry for "Horanimal" and "Purple" at the end of cols `A` & `B` the tables automatically expand...*
[image]

*If I add another entry for Horanimal with a different color you'll see the count for Purple drops from 1 to 0 because there are no longer any people just in Purple:*
[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: The actual data I'm processing has a lot of names (1000+).

I only want the number of people. (eg. X number of people have Red (but not Orange, Green, Blue).

Comment: @Bez no worries, just added steps 4 & 5 to the answer which accomplish this goal and will work no many how many names or colors you have! [see example sheet here as well](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-lmlpOaWSLjEe8zMOu5krma5dpZXHITqXEmPsnppD8o/edit#gid=1067760214&range=E3)